# what is standard way to create Push Topic in Salesforce

Tags: pushtopic, push-notification

In My Salesforce Org I have not created any **PushTopic** but when i query on PushTopic it show 100 Push Topic.

I have not found any trigger in my org which creates push topic.

Is Their some standard functionality to create PushTopic or its related to managed Package Code?

I have not found anything how these Push Topic Created

Comment: any apex can do it, managed or unmanaged

Comment: how I stop a push topic from being created?

Comment: Contact vendor of packages installed and ask them why do they need it and scan your org for any apex that creates push topics, and remove that logic

Comment: I have checked their is no process in my org to create push topic, if it's related to manage package, why some push topic created for my custom object/custom metadata and custom setting

Comment: It is possible to call getdescribe to get all objects, even unmanaged, and create a push topic for every single object if necessary. You should really contact vendors of your packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Salesforce does not create any PushTopics by default. There must be some process that is creating such topics.

You might want to check the below things

1. Check if there is any managed package installed in your org and is creating the push topics.
2. Check if there is any integration happening with any system which requires the push topics creation.
3. Also, check the created by id of the push topic and see which user is creating those.

Getting the created by information will give you more context on this.

Comment: I have checked their is no process in my org to create push topic, if it's related to manage package, why some push topic created for my custom object/custom metadata and custom setting